# How to save, with anonymous authentication, to Firebase database - using Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutter, firebase-security

I'm getting permission denied after I have authenticated with Anonymous Auth

```
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (21033): PlatformException(-3, Permission denied, )
...
_getCurrentUser: FirebaseUser({providerId: firebase, uid: DOIL...............u54j1, displayName: , email: , isAnonymous: true, isEmailVerified: false, providerData: [{providerId: firebase, uid: DOIL//////////////54j1, displayName: , email: }]})
```

My rules on the Firebase DB are

```
{
  "rules": {
    //Test rule
//     "users": {
//   "$uid": {
//     ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
//     ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
//       }
//    }

//       General rule - closed to everyone but app uses
         ".read": "auth != null",
         ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

The code I use to save data - works fine with DB rules set to open to all.

```
      _saveUserData(UserEntry userData) async {

    print("_saveUserData jsonData =" userData.toJson().toString());

    // SAVE MY DATA TO DB
    // tUsers = db reference to the child node users on Firebase
    _tUsers.push().set(talentUserData.toJson());


  }
```

What am I doing wrong ?  Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `"auth != null"` means that you need to be authenticated. you can use `"true"` instead to allow anonymous read/write, but be cautious because this means any user with any client applications can modify your firebase data.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So what is the point of  "Anonymous Authentication" ?

Comment: Allowing anybody (even anonymous) to read is fine for non-sensitive data. Also allowing anonymous to write values of a certain structure to a certain path might make sense. Just allowing anonymous to allow write without restriction is hazardous to your app and probably also to your finances if you're unlucky and someone misuses your database with high volume data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hope of saving someone a headache. I found the problem to be not getting a fresh instance of the Firebase Database.  I created the instance in my main.dart and passed it to my HomePage in the constructor (per the example file in the library).

When I got a fresh instance ...out of desperation debugging...it worked.  I can now have anonymous login so that only people who have installed the app can write to the database.